# Show conditional alert based on product supplier in shopify

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid, cart, shopping-cart

i'm running a dropshipping store on shopify, dawn theme, where i get the products from 2 different suppliers who obviously ships separate.

I need to add a custom script to check the location.id for each product added into the cart, if the location id are different than i would like to show a notification to the customer saying '' This order will be delivered with 2 separate shipping" so i though to write something like this :

```
{%- for item in cart.items -%}
    {%- if location.id[i] != location.id[j]-%}
<div><h2>This order will be delivered with 2 separate shipping</h2></div>
{%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

I've looked around but i did not find any solution regarding this matter.
I think the above script should work, but i'm not sure at all (i'm skilled in php, js) but not in liquid.

Is there somebody who can help me to solve this matter?

Moreover, in which file should i add this script?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing within the Shopify Liquid object model present in themes that would let you return the product variants' inventory location. Neither does any query object exist withing the Storefront API that might enable implementing this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shopify Product Metafields that can be set up for each specific product/variant (https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/metafield).

So adding location id for each product metafield will do the trick

```
{% assign suppliersAmount = 0 %}
{% assign cartSuppliersList = "" %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% assign productSupplierId = item.product.metafields.my_fields.location %}
    
    {% if cartSuppliersList contains productSupplierId %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign cartSuppliersList = cartSuppliersList | append: productSupplierId %}
      {% assign suppliersAmount = suppliersAmount | plus: 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if suppliersAmount > 1 %}
    <div><h2>This order will be delivered with 2 separate shipping</h2></div>
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this solution start looking good but i have one more question, the products are automatically sync with the shop through two different third party app(one for each supplier) and shopify recognize this apps as product location/wharehouse; is there any way to use this location of shopify instead of metafields? As the shop has more than 4k products and every day we import new and using metafields would be a crazy job. Thank you very much.